# Crawling in a Json response in scrapy

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, scrapy

After having spent the entire day on trying to solve my problem, I come to you in order to seek for some help... I am currently building a web scrawler with scrapy but I can not import correctly my json file.

The structure of the json is as follows:

```
  {
  "Response": "Success",
  "Type": 100,
  "Aggregated": false,
  "Data": [
    {
      "time": 1452643200,
      "close": 1.21,
      "high": 1.21,
      "low": 1.21,
      "open": 1.21,
      "volumefrom": 0,
      "volumeto": 0
    },
    {
      "time": 1452646800,
      "close": 1.21,
      "high": 1.21,
      "low": 1.21,
      "open": 1.21,
      "volumefrom": 0,
      "volumeto": 0
        }
  ],
  "TimeTo": 1452679200,
  "TimeFrom": 1452643200,
  "FirstValueInArray": true,
  "ConversionType": "direct"
}
```

Whenever I call:

```
        json_string = response.body_as_unicode()
    for Data in json_string:
        for close in Data:
            print close
```

I encounter two different problems:

- I can not retrieve items from within "Data", as it appears to be a string and I can not imput any arguments.
- The print function prints vertically all returned data.

My wish is to retrieve the data and later on to be able to say that when (for example) "high" = 0, the crawler must stop.

Thanks for your help in advance and sorry if I'm not clear somewhere.

M.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string first:

```
import json

d = json.loads(json_string)
for rec in d['Data']:
    if rec['high'] == 0:
        break
    print(rec['close'])
```